# Unslider - Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm actually using Unslider - https://github.com/idiot/unslider
I used it the same way in past project, so at first I'll do some explanation. 
First frame slides images, images-list displays all images which changes class to active.
Also on click for any image from list it displays in in main slider.

Now it displays me in console "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined" @ unslider-settings.js?ver=4.3.1:7

I tried diffrent ways and nothing seems to fix it. Any ideas?

```
var sliderData;


function restart_slider() {
    'use strict';
    if (sliderData) {
        var sliderIndex = jQuery(sliderData.items[sliderData.current]).index();
        var galleryList = jQuery('.images-single');
        var galleryDom = galleryList.map(function () { return jQuery(this); });

        galleryList.removeClass('active');
        galleryDom[sliderData.current].addClass('active');

        galleryList.click(function (event) {
            var clicked = jQuery(this);
            var clickedIndex = clicked.index();

            galleryList.removeClass('active');
            clicked.addClass('active');

            sliderData.move(clickedIndex);
        });

    }

}

jQuery(document).ready(function () {

'use strict';
var slider = jQuery('.banner').unslider({
    autoplay:true,
    speed: 500,
    arrows: true,
    //prev:'',
    //next:'',
    complete: restart_slider
});

sliderData = slider.data('unslider');

restart_slider();
});
```

Comment: Does the error message come with a line number? What does unslider-setttings.js contain?

Comment: Yes it's line :7. Unslider-settings.js contain code I put above.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it was matter of diffrent unslider. Before I download it from unslider.com, now I did it from github.